# Calculate age from datebirth sql field

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate Age in MySQL (InnoDb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773405/calculate-age-in-mysql-innodb)

I have created a table and one of its columns is 'dob' (date of birth). It entered the birth date in the table in 0000-00-00 format. But I need to display my users ($id) with their age instead of the 0000-00-00 format.

My current page is displaying the info from my database in this format. It will display the age of different users.

`<td align="center"><? echo $rows['age']; ?></td>`

Comment: What units?  Years?  Days?  Months?  Age alone is like speed or weight.  Units need to accompany it.

Comment: Also, you don't specify if the last `00-00` of your date string is `mm-dd` or `dd-mm`.

Comment: @msanford with MySQL it's safe to assume yyyy-mm-dd.  But, 0000-00-0000 is indeed vague.  He should have specified the type of the field instead unless it's varchar in which the format of the date would need to be explicity stated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a SQL query you can use.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), '1982-01-01')))) AS age
```

Comment: And now having seen the comments above, a caveat:  That's assuming the data type of the column dob is date or datetime.

Comment: I placed: `SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM users(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), '1982-01-01')))) AS age` but didn't work

Comment: Could you elaborate on "but didn't work"?  You are using MySQL, right?
`root@beren [~]# mysql`

`Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.`

`Your MySQL connection id is 13408`

`Server version: 5.0.95-community MySQL Community Edition (GPL)`

``

`mysql> SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), '1982-01-01')))) AS age;`

`+------+`

`| age  |`

`+------+`

`|   30 |`

`+------+`

`1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

``

`mysql>`


Hoping the comment formatting works...and it doesn't seem to be.