# From a birthday date list to an array of the total user from each individual age

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I will like to understand the most efficient way to achieve this:

I have a MySQL table with my users info, including birthday (YYYY/MM/DD). My objective is to retrieve an array (php) with the total of user for each individual age from 10 to 60 years old. I can just query all my users, pass the birthday to a *birthday to age* php function I wrote and then populate an array with the totals. But I wonder if there's a way to build an sql query that does this job for me?

Comment: Searching `mysql birthday` on SO gets me a lot of hits, are they not helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+birthday

Comment: done that, but seems no body ask something like this

Comment: This should help: [Calculate Age in MySQL (InnoDb)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5773405)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to group the rows:

```
SELECT
    FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), `birthday`)/365) AS 'Age',
    COUNT(*)
FROM `users`
WHERE FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), `birthday`)/365) BETWEEN 10 AND 60
AND `id` IN (1, 3, 5, 12, 29)
GROUP BY FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), `birthday`)/365)
ORDER BY FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), `birthday`)/365) ASC
```

The result won't contain ages that have no users, but I'm not sure why you'd need that.

**Updates**
 - Added an id filter
 - Fixed the date calculation (oops!)
 - Named the new column

Comment: This could do the trick, but i wonder, what if instead of retrieving all the users i retrieve just the ones with specific Ids, like passing an array of ids on the query, can you please show me how to modify your query in order to achieve this?

Comment: I've added that to my answer

Comment: Why don't you alias ``YEAR(NOW() - `birthday`)``?

Comment: The operation year(now() - birthday) is giving me an strange result: http://postimage.org/image/7k092fvtn/

Comment: @DomingoSL it's because the column isn't named, so the name is taken from the calculation - see my updated answer.

Comment: the error is not the label, is that 2013 value, what it means? i dont have users with 2013 year old

Comment: Oops, sorry - I've fixed a calculation error (didn't have mysql to hand earlier)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tableName 
         WHERE dateOfBirth >= (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 60 YEAR)   
         AND dateOfBirth <= ( CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 10 YEAR )
```

Hopefully I don't get slammed by the database experts on this one...

Comment: That would get you all the users between 10-60 years old. The OP wants a count of users per year (of age)

Comment: Good code though - I always get really stuck with MySQL intervals

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use MySql's [DATEDIFF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff).

```
SELECT USER, DATEOFBIRTH FROM USERTABLE WHERE DATEDIFF(DATEOFBIRTH,NOW()) < 60;
```