# Calculate age based on date of birth

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a table of users in sql and they each have birth dates. I want to convert their date of birth to their age (years only), e.g. date: `15.03.1999` age: 14 and `15.03.2014` will change to age: `15`

Here I want to show the date of the user:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
    $dnn = mysql_fetch_array($dn);
    $dn = mysql_query('select username, email, skype, avatar, ' .
        'date, signup_date, gender from users where id="'.$id.'"');
    $dnn = mysql_fetch_array($dn);
    echo "{$dnn['date']}";
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate Age in MySQL (InnoDb)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773405/calculate-age-in-mysql-innodb)

Comment: presumably your dates are stored using a date data type?

Comment: there are plenty of 'calculate age' answers out there. Google is a mighty tool! But by the way: Don't use mysql_* functions. Use PDO or MySQLi

Comment: Get current date/time and subtract the converted one from database...then convert it back to number of years, use strtotime() and date() with proper formatting.

Comment: Isn't it amazing that no one's ever had to do this before.

Comment: Is this a MySQL problem, or a PHP problem? Also, be warned that the given query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Answer (score 217, accepted):

## PHP <sup>>= 5.3.0</sup>

```php
# object oriented
$from = new DateTime('1970-02-01');
$to   = new DateTime('today');
echo $from->diff($to)->y;

# procedural
echo date_diff(date_create('1970-02-01'), date_create('today'))->y;
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/84187)</kbd>

<sup>functions: [`date_create()`](http://php.net/date_create), [`date_diff()`](http://php.net/date_diff)</sup>

---

## MySQL <sup>>= 5.0.0</sup>

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '1970-02-01', CURDATE()) AS age
```

<kbd>[**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/23465)</kbd>

<sup>functions: [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff), [`CURDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)</sup>

Comment: @PHPupil: `date_diff` is for PHP version >= 5.3.0.

Comment: @PHPupil: upgrade PHP? ;) or use MySQL solution.

Comment: This wouldn't work for dob's that are under 1 years old... showing 0 is not necessarily ideal for age

Comment: @RymanHolmes: if you need to show 1 year old, instead of 0, show it. One simple if statement solves this. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 8):

Got this script from net (thanks to coffeecupweb)

```
<?php
/**
 * Simple PHP age Calculator
 * 
 * Calculate and returns age based on the date provided by the user.
 * @param   date of birth('Format:yyyy-mm-dd').
 * @return  age based on date of birth
 */
function ageCalculator($dob){
    if(!empty($dob)){
        $birthdate = new DateTime($dob);
        $today   = new DateTime('today');
        $age = $birthdate->diff($today)->y;
        return $age;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
$dob = '1992-03-18';
echo ageCalculator($dob);
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

Very small code to get Age:

```
<?php
    $dob='1981-10-07';
    $diff = (date('Y') - date('Y',strtotime($dob)));
    echo $diff;
?>

//output 35
```

Comment: How did this get 11 votes? A person's age depends on the day and month of the year as well.

Comment: Your method is incorrect if person have DOB ex. 13-10-1991 and current month is July then the age is 27 which is wrong. The person age is 26 till the current month is equal to or greater then the DOB month.

Answer (score 5):

```
$hours_in_day   = 24;
$minutes_in_hour= 60;
$seconds_in_mins= 60;

$birth_date     = new DateTime("1988-07-31T00:00:00");
$current_date   = new DateTime();

$diff           = $birth_date->diff($current_date);

echo $years     = $diff->y . " years " . $diff->m . " months " . $diff->d . " day(s)"; echo "<br/>";
echo $months    = ($diff->y * 12) + $diff->m . " months " . $diff->d . " day(s)"; echo "<br/>";
echo $weeks     = floor($diff->days/7) . " weeks " . $diff->d%7 . " day(s)"; echo "<br/>";
echo $days      = $diff->days . " days"; echo "<br/>";
echo $hours     = $diff->h + ($diff->days * $hours_in_day) . " hours"; echo "<br/>";
echo $mins      = ($diff->h * $minutes_in_hour) + ($diff->days * $hours_in_day * $minutes_in_hour) . " minutest"; echo "<br/>";
echo $seconds   = ($diff->h * $minutes_in_hour * $seconds_in_mins) + ($diff->days * $hours_in_day * $minutes_in_hour * $seconds_in_mins) . " seconds"; echo "<br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

For a birthday date with format **Date/Month/Year**

```
function age($birthday){
 list($day, $month, $year) = explode("/", $birthday);
 $year_diff  = date("Y") - $year;
 $month_diff = date("m") - $month;
 $day_diff   = date("d") - $day;
 if ($day_diff < 0 && $month_diff==0) $year_diff--;
 if ($day_diff < 0 && $month_diff < 0) $year_diff--;
 return $year_diff;
}
```

or the same function that accepts day, month, year as parameters :

```
function age($day, $month, $year){
 $year_diff  = date("Y") - $year;
 $month_diff = date("m") - $month;
 $day_diff   = date("d") - $day;
 if ($day_diff < 0 && $month_diff==0) $year_diff--;
 if ($day_diff < 0 && $month_diff < 0) $year_diff--;
 return $year_diff;
}
```

You can use it like this :

```
echo age("20/01/2000");
```

which will output the correct age (On 4 June, it's 14).

Answer (score 0):

declare `@dateOfBirth date`
`select @dateOfBirth = '2000-01-01'`

`SELECT datediff(YEAR,@dateOfBirth,getdate()) as Age`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $dob = $this->dateOfBirth; //Datetime 
        $currentDate = new \DateTime();
        $dateDiff = $dob->diff($currentDate);
        $years = $dateDiff->y;
        $months = $dateDiff->m;
        $days = $dateDiff->d;
        $age = $years .' Year(s)';

        if($years === 0) {
            $age = $months .' Month(s)';
            if($months === 0) {
                $age = $days .' Day(s)';
            }
        }
        return $age;
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope you will find this useful.

```
$query1="SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF (YEAR, YOUR_DOB_COLUMN, CURDATE()) AS age FROM your_table WHERE id='$user_id'";
$res1=mysql_query($query1);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($res1);
echo $row['age'];
```

Comment: Please don't recommend the usage of insecure queries

Answer (score -1):

```
$getyear = explode("-", $value['users_dob']);
$dob = date('Y') - $getyear[0];
```

`$value['users_dob']` is the database value with format `yyyy-mm-dd`

Answer (score -3):

To Calculate age from Date of birth used used query like this.

```
'SELECT username, email, skype, avatar, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date, CURDATE()) AS age, signup_date, gender FROM users WHERE id="'.$id.'"';


if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);

    $dn = mysql_query('select username, email, skype, avatar, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date, CURDATE()) AS age, signup_date, gender from users where id="'.$id.'"');

    $dnn = mysql_fetch_array($dn);

    echo $dnn['age'];
}
```

Note: don't use reserved keywords column name.

Comment: Please don't recommend the usage of insecure queries

Comment: Have you seen the question and what creator asking for. I am only trying to help him for getting Date Of Birth. that is why i used creator query not mine.