# How to store and publish a date of birth?

Tags: php, forms, date

I want to store a user's date of birth, publish it and show the age. I know how to store the date of birth, but I do not know how I could echo the age afterwards.

I want it like:

> username - 06/02/1992 (22 years)

How do I do this?

Comment: What did you try...?? Where is your code...??

Comment: The [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) library is your best friend for PHP date calculations and manipulation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [calculate age based on date of birth](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19521323/67332)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you just need to use the date() function to format it.

This answer will help if you're using MySQL and will also describe the basics of formatting dates.
[Convert from MySQL datetime to another format with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136782/convert-from-mysql-datetime-to-another-format-with-php)