# PHP - Use date 'yyyy/mm/dd' to show age, POST data

Tags: php, html, date, http-post

I'm trying to get posted data of someones birthday, to send over to another page and display their age, so far I've got this which works

```
<?php
$c= date('Y');
$y= date('Y', strtotime('1993-12-29'));
echo $c - $y;
?>
```

But how would I do this with posted data? I've tried:

```
$c= date('Y');
$y= date('Y',strtotime($_POST['sBirthday']));
echo $c-$y;
```

Although this doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: Check the *actual* value with `var_dump($_POST['sBirthday']);`. For php it does not really matter where it comes from. What matters is the value.

Comment: Show your form... Also you can var_dump($_POST) to see what is sent...

Comment: Problem's most likely in your form. How's it's used, the method, missing name attribute; could be anything. Input in it would need to follow what you have `1993-12-29` or `19951229`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP calculate age](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776682/php-calculate-age)

Comment: `19951229` I meant `19931229` but it's not much different. Give/take a few years ;-)

Comment: Duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/a/19521323/67332](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19521323/67332).

Comment: @Glavić I do not think, this is his question, since he assumes that the first code works; even though it includes the same problem, which to solve you imply would be the question... but it clearly is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your posted code will work with the according HTML-Form if the person puts it in correctly. For example this form will work, if the user types `1993-12-29`:

```html
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="date" name="sBirthday" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

2. Your code does not actually calculate the age of a person. Think, somebody is born on 2014-12-31; would you say he is `1` year old (this is what your code would calculate)? In fact he is `0` years old, because he did not live for a full year yet.

   To calculate the age of a person try as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776682/php-calculate-age#answer-3776741):

```php
$date = new DateTime($_POST['sBirthday']);
$now = new DateTime();
$interval = $now->diff($date);
echo $interval->y;
```

Comment: *"For example this form will work, if the user types `1993-12-29`"* - As will `19931229` - It will use the first four integers.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Actually, no. The [manual states](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) that the first argument to the constructor of DateTime is 'A date/time string. Valid formats are explained in [Date and Time Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).'. The list of viable formats does not contain `YYMMDD` which would be what you suggested (`19931229`). Or did I understand your comment wrong?

Comment: My bad, however I was referring to OP's code using `strtotime` and not about yours.