# Getting age in years - SQL / PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, sql

i want to see the age in years of my clients in my database.

The table is called 'clients' and the clients have set a birth of date (example:1992-04-04). But i want to see it like this: Age: 17 (for example).
How can i do this?

I need the SQL Query for this.. i tried DATEDIFF but i just cant get it working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calculate age based on date of birth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521146/calculate-age-based-on-date-of-birth)

Comment: Tag dbms used. (DATEDIFF is a product specific function...)

Comment: Also, that client is 24 years old...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,'2003-05-01', NOW());
```

Of course you put your birthdate selected from proper table instead of '2003-05-01' :-)