# How to calculate age from date of birth in clojure?

Tags: datetime, clojure

I have a date of birth variable in my program in the format "1954-09-15". How can I find the age of that person using this date of birth?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521146/calculate-age-based-on-date-of-birth

Comment: i need the result in clojure language (in years)

Comment: have you looked in to using clj-time https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time

Comment: To be fair to the OP, this question is [massively upvoted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c?rq=1) for other languages. That being said, @MelvinSGeorge, the answer is easily found in existing online documentation and blogs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116123/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Clojure it is common to use `clj-time` for processing having to do with time. But if you don't want to pull an additional dependency you can use `java.time` for your problem. You need to understand Java interop from Clojure, though, as you would be using a Java library through Clojure.

First you have to import the necessary java dependencies through `import`.

Inside the function `age` you create a `date-formatter` for the pattern that your input string (the birthdate of the person) has - in this case it's `"yyyy-MM-dd"`.

Then you parse the input using the created `date-formatter` to create a `LocalDate` object.

After that you create another `LocalDate` object that holds the time at the moment of execution.

In the end you calculate the difference between the two created `LocalDate` objects, expressed in years (`ChronoUnit/YEARS').

```
(ns age-of-person.core
  (:import (java.time LocalDate
                      format.DateTimeFormatter
                      Year
                      temporal.ChronoUnit)))

    (defn age [birthdate]
      (let [date-formatter (DateTimeFormatter/ofPattern "yyyy-MM-dd")
            birthdate (LocalDate/parse birthdate date-formatter)
            now (LocalDate/now)
            age (.until birthdate now ChronoUnit/YEARS)]
        age))
```

Calling the method `age` would look like this:

```
age-of-person.core=> (age "1954-09-15")
62
```