# Update age column in database using php mysqli or pdo

Tags: php, mysql

How to update age automatically based on its DOB? I'm planning to write a script that fetch DOB column then calculate the age and update it. I started my idea but it still doesn't meet my objective.

Pls. help! Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Comment: in my opinion don't store age, store dob and calculate age whenever needed.

Comment: @tan how do i do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749639/how-to-get-the-difference-in-years-from-two-different-dates

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521146/calculate-age-based-on-date-of-birth

That should help you out

Comment: So what you want is when the user fills his DOB the age field will be autocompleted with the age number?

Comment: seems what you need is to watch php tutorials first

Comment: @pr1nc3 no, I want to auto update my age in database based on stored DOB..

Comment: @Beginner yes, that's why I'm asking here. Maybe I can get ideas on how to do my project..

Comment: in my opinion if you do this every time php run, due to more traffic the execution time would be slow as @tan said you should try to calculate ages in php. not in database

Comment: @tan 

Thanks, I realized that's a better idea. I'll try to do that.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu

Thanks.. I got the idea now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an age column when you have already date of birth, is slightly futile. Also, this means you would need to update the value once a year for every record, and at their birth date. That will start to get heavier and heavier. A lot of comments suggested to do the calculation of the age in PHP, this also would get heavy if you wanted to group people by age, you'd have to grab every records of the database and calculate their age. My suggestion is to use MySQL to calculate it, so you can use it in joins, where clauses, group bys and so on...

```
SELECT YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(birthdate) - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(birthdate, '%m%d')) as age FROM table
```

For more details, this was taken from [How to get the difference in years from two different dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749639/how-to-get-the-difference-in-years-from-two-different-dates) which accounts for leap years.

You could easily create a MySQL function, call it calc_age or something and pass it the birthdate, that would return the current age and would be very easy to use...

Comment: I got your idea.. I didn't realized it earlier there's an easy way to solve my issue.