# How do I calculate a user's age given a date of birth?

Tags: php

I need to calculate ages depended on birthday from a table of customers.

This is my code:

```
// customer age
function calculate_customer_age($startDate,$endDate){
    $endDate=date(m-d-y);
    $startDate= $customer['birthday'];
    $fromDate= new DateTime($startDate);
    $toDate= new DateTime($endDate);
    echo $fromDate->diff($toDate)->days;
}
```

In the last row, I need to echo age calculated depended on retrieve from a table of a customer from `MySQL`.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Errors? Wrong result? Btw, you can remove the `$endDate` variable completely. If you just do `$toDate = new DateTime()` you will get the current date.

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo, but `date(m-d-y)` should be `date('m-d-y')`.

Comment: What do you want to achieve from this code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate age based on date of birth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521146/calculate-age-based-on-date-of-birth)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code in your function, which will calculate age upto today. You can modify $today to use the end date and format you want.

```
$dateOfBirth = $customer['birthday'];
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$diff = date_diff(date_create($dateOfBirth), date_create($today));
echo 'Age is '.$diff->format('%y');
```

Answer (score 0):

You had several errors in your `calculate_customer_age` function, instead you can use the below code to get the difference in days between two dates:

```
function calculate_customer_age($startDate, $endDate)
{
    $startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", $startDate);
    $endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y", $endDate);
    return $startDate->diff($endDate)->days;
}

echo calculate_customer_age("11/30/2008", "08/23/2018"); // 3553
```

**Documentation:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors in your code. There is no need to pass end date in your function. You can use the following code to get the age.

```
function calculate_customer_age($startDate){
    $fromDate = new DateTime($startDate);
    $toDate       = new DateTime('today');
    return $fromDate->diff($toDate)->days;
       // or return $fromDate->diff($toDate)->y;
}

echo calculate_customer_age($customer['birthday']);
```

Answer (score 0):

**PHP >= 5.3.0**

## object oriented

```
$from = new DateTime('1970-02-01');
$to   = new DateTime('today');
echo $from->date_diff($to)->y;
```

## procedural

```
echo date_diff(date_create('1970-02-01'), date_create('today'))->y;
```

**MySQL >= 5.0.0**

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '1970-02-01', CURDATE()) AS age
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate customer's age in days, you should do so:

```
function calculate_customer_age($startDate){
        $fromDate= new DateTime($startDate);
        $toDate= new DateTime();
        $difference = $fromDate->diff($toDate)->days;
        return $difference->format('%a');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> php code

```
$startDate = '05-01-1988'; // sample start date or dob
$end_Date = '23-08-2018'; // smmple end date

echo calculate_customer_age( $startDate , $end_Date );
```

> php function that returns age -

```
function calculate_customer_age( $startDate , $endDate ) //function returns age   
{   
    $diff = date_diff( date_create( $startDate  ), date_create( $endDate ) );
    return $diff->format('%y Years, %m Months, %d Days');
}
```

**Sample Output :**

> 30 Years, 7 Months, 18 Days