# MySQL Age from Date of Birth (ignore nulls)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to calculate age from Date of Birth, which I was able to do successfully using [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773405/calculate-age-in-mysql-innodb). However, some of my DateOfBirth have null values, and using my below formula, the result coms back as "2012" instead of (blank/null).

**Here is my table:**

```
10/06/1990
01/09/1998
*null*
*null*
02/16/1991
```

**Here is my desired result:**

```
23
25
(blank)
(blank)
22
```

**Here is my formula so far:**

```
year(curdate())-year(user.DateOfBirth) - (dayofyear(curdate()) < dayofyear(user.DateOfBirth)) AS 'Age'
```

**Here is what I'm actually getting:**

```
23
25
2012
2012
22
```

**Here are a couple of things I've tried to eliminate the "2012", which results in some encrypted text:**

```
IF(user.DateOfBirth > '0001-01-01',AboveFormula,'')
CASE AboveFormula WHEN 2012 THEN '' ELSE AboveFormula END AS 'Age'
```

Comment: Dates are stored as DATE data types, right?

Comment: DateOfBirth is stored as datetime

Comment: NULLs are not stored in the field.  NULL is a hidden status bit elsewhere in the record.  That is why a special mechanism must be used to test whether a field is NULL:  `DateOfBirth IS NOT NULL` or `DateOfBirth IS NULL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  CASE
            WHEN user.DateOfBirth IS NULL THEN ""
            ELSE year(curdate())-year(user.DateOfBirth) - (dayofyear(curdate()) < dayofyear(user.DateOfBirth)) 
        END AS 'Age'
FROM    myTable
```

Comment: This results in encrypted text, like 0x32303132 or 0x3233 (using LinqPad)

Comment: Seems to work just fine here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0177e/2/0  I added an ID column in the sqlfiddle just to delineate the rows better.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
CASE
WHEN DateOfBirth IS NULL THEN ""
ELSE 
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(DateOfBirth , '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(DateOfBirth , '00-%m-%d')) 
END AS age
FROM    myTable
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted `IS NULL THEN ''` or a blank result in the case of missing data.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT IF(user.DateOfBirth IS NULL,"",
          YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(user.DateOfBirth)
          - IF(DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) < DAYOFYEAR(user.DateOfBirth),1,0)
         ) as 'Age'
FROM user
```