# What SQL better for calculated members age? (MySQL MYISAM)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to show my members age in profile page.
I found 2 SQL queries:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()) AS age FROM users
```

and

```
SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), dob) / 365)
```

What SQL query better?? (For performance, accurate etc.)

Comment: There is more that 365 days in a year. That is why we have leap years.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate Age in MySQL (InnoDb)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773405/calculate-age-in-mysql-innodb)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how this will translate into mysql. But here is a T-SQL that can calculate age for a person, given their birth date and current date.

```
select case 
            when cast(getdate() as date) = cast(dateadd(year, (datediff(year, '1996-09-09', getdate())), '1996-09-09') as date)
                then dateDiff(yyyy,'1996-09-09',dateadd(year, 0, getdate()))
            else dateDiff(yyyy,'1996-09-09',dateadd(year, -1, getdate()))
        end as MemberAge
go
```