# Fetch people between a certain age from your MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, date

Well, let's say I've got the following table:

```
+----+-----------+--------+------------------+
| id | name      | gender | birthDate (date) |
+----+-----------+--------+------------------+
| 1  | John Doe  | Male   | 1968-09-18       |
| 2  | Jane Doe  | Female | 1970-11-20       |
| 3  | Sally Doe | Female | 1985-04-17       |
| 4  | Jake Doe  | Male   | 1989-07-10       |
| 5  | Mike Doe  | Male   | 1991-06-28       |
| 6  | Cindy Doe | Female | 1995-02-03       |
+----+-----------+--------+------------------+
```

How would I get everyone older than 21 and younger than 50 from this table. I can normally find my way in mysql but when it comes to dates I always seem to mess up.

Comment: Important question: is the birthDate column type a DATE or string? because that's not how mysql stores dates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate Age in MySQL (InnoDb)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773405/calculate-age-in-mysql-innodb)

Comment: @STTLCU It will be a date field, I will edit the question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way using BETWEEN statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE birthdate BETWEEN
(curdate() - interval 50 year)
AND 
(curdate() - interval 21 year)
```

Comment: Curious, is one of the two answers better (i.e. in performance)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from your_table
where curdate() - interval 21 year >= birthDate 
and curdate() - interval 50 year < birthDate
```