# How could i search age from database birth day field?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to find age from mysql database field name birthday.
Ex. if anyone's data of birth is 25-07-1991 then i want to query his present age from mysql database.
please someone help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773405/calculate-age-in-mysql-innodb

Comment: This should help: [Calculate age](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773405/calculate-age-in-mysql-innodb) in combination with a simple WHERE birthday = date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I've correctly understanded the question. 
The query could be something like:

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE birthday = '1991-07-25'

If you want to get the age instead, I will try making a query like this:

> SELECT (CURDATE()-birthday) FROM table WHERE ?

or I will make it via code, doing first a query to get the date of birth like:

> SELECT birthday FROM table WHERE ?

and than doing a subtraction

Answer (score 0):

If birthday is the name of the field containing the date of birth, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(birthday) FROM table WHERE ?;
```