# SQL Date between 6 weeks and 16 years

Tags: mysql, sql, database, list, date

I need to calculate some dates in SQL.

I want all results where the age is between 6 weeks and 16 years old.

Not sure what the most sensible way to go about this is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your table structure and maybe some data.

Comment: Whatever the most sensible way turns out to be, it ain't going to be this.

Comment: Similar: [Calculate Age in MySQL (InnoDb)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5773405/642706)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a date field that represents the birth date, you need to calculate the age (with the help of NOW() function), and get only records that match your criteria. something like this:

```
select * from table
where (DATEDIFF(NOW(), birth_date)/7) > 16 /*16 weeks*/
and  (DATEDIFF(NOW(), birth_date)/365) < 16 /*16 years*/
```