# PHP Get Age function does not working on Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using **CodeIgniter with php5.6**

```
public function getUserAge($uid=''){
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $res = $this->db->select("age(dob, '$today') as age")->from('users')->where(array('user_id' => $uid))->get()->row_array();

    return $res['age'];
}
```

but I get **error**.

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1305
>
> FUNCTION tblname.age does not exist
>
> SELECT age('dob', '2019-02-11') as age FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` =
>   53
>
> Filename: modules/account/models/Account_model.php
>
> Line Number: 142

Comment: age in not a  mysql function

Comment: Which database are you using? age() is not a mysql function.

Comment: im using MySQL in Cpanel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate Age in MySQL (InnoDb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773405/calculate-age-in-mysql-innodb)

Comment: Also see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-calculations.html

Answer (score 0):

age is  not a mysql function.

If you want age in mysql you could use  a query as

```
SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(dob) - 
        IF(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', MONTH(dob), '-', DAY(dob)) ,'%Y-%c-%e') 
    > CURDATE(), 1, 0) 
AS age
```

FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = 53