# SQL. Convert age to date of birth

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I was surprised when I did not find any mention of converting age to DOB  (date of birth). There are many answers about converting DOB to age, but not vice versa.

I have two digits (I able to convert them to any data type, even into DateTime.date (python-format)). 
How I can convert them to a full SQL date. It must be current_date - age (day and month are not important to me). It is preferable to do this by the database, not by the python.

DDL:

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
user_id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
goal VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
age INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
gender VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
country VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
city VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
comment VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL)""")
```

p.s. related questions [Calculate Age in MySQL (InnoDb)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5773405/11277611)

Comment: What's a dirth ?

Comment: typo, date of birth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL 8.x you can use `INTERVAL` arithmetic. For example:

```
select current_date() - interval 42 year
```

Result:

```
1978-05-21
```

In your case this could translate to:

```
select current_date() - interval age year from users;
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/73gQRQmSjp1KfL5LzGeX2Z/0).