Calculate years without so many variables
Is there a way to calculate the age (years completed) of the user in PHP or from MySQL directly without using so many vars? I mean, what is the shortest code/way ?
In MySQL the date is stored like this: 2010-12-26 using DATE
The PHP is working like this:
    <?php
        $birthday = new DateTime($result['birthday']);
        $now = new DateTime();
        $age = $now->diff($birthday);
        echo $age -> y;
    ?>

My question is if it is possible to shorten this for example like this:
    <?php
        echo new DateTime()->diff->$row['birthday'] -> y;
    ?>


Have you looked at doing this in the query instead (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773405/calculate-age-in-mysql-innodb)

Well you can always just substitute the variables: echo new DateTime()->diff(new DateTime($result['birthday']))->y; but in general the goal should be to write code that's easy to read and maintain, not code that's as short as possible

I tried echo new DateTime()->diff(new DateTime($result['birthday']))->y; but get error unexpected ; - T_object_operator

Oops, you need some parentheses there. echo (new DateTime())->diff(new DateTime($result['birthday']))->y; Again, I don't recommend doing this.

working perfect, thanks Guy. If you want to add it as answer I will select it as the correct one

Calculate the age on MySQL side with simple SELECT .. , TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday, CURRENT_DATE) AS age, ..

I don't want to write an answer for something that I believe is wrong to do. The original code is just fine and easy to understand; the one-liner is more complicated for a human reader but exactly the same for the computer so you don't win anything by changing the code

Do this
echo date_diff(date_create($result['birthday']), date_create('today'))->y;


this gives me almost correct years. But because the birthday is in September the age should be for example 24 and not 25

It should work now

@New-Girl please give us the exact value of $result['birthday'] in that case, instead of something as vague and imprecise as "the birthday is in September" (we can not even tell what the year actually is, from that.)

What she is trying to say : say birthday is 2010-09-10, that means the age is 13 years 9 month as of June 2024.
